# element distinctness probllem in O(log n)??? How is this done?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am working on this sample midterm from 2008 in an algorithms class that was provided to us if we want to prepare for our own midterm. One of the question is on the element distinctness problem. Essentially it says this (My own paraphrasing):

> Given a sorted array (assume ascending order and not-strictly increasing), we want to find out if the array has at least 10 distinct elements.

Then the question goes on and asks to *describe an algorithm that runs in O(n)*, which is so simple it doesn't even take discussion, and then it asks to *describe an algorithm for this problem that runs in O(log n)*. OOOOH MYYYY GOD!!!

If I have an array of only 12 elements, then I have to do some operation(perhaps comparison) and immediately throw out 6 elements! This dooms me to failure even if 10 of the elements are indeed distinct! So I don't see how on Earth I can do this in O(log n) time.

I tried this algorithm:

> Split n into 2T(n/2) subproblems. Then split into 4(n/4) and so on until I have many subarrays of only 2 elements. Then throw out one of the identical elements and increase a counter, "count" for the thrown out elements. Then at the end subtract counter from n and observe if the result is 10 or more.

This obviously is flawed in MANY MANY ways:

- I am not throwing out half elements in each step
- I have no way to check for one element in one subarray and one element from another subarray

If I think further, I will probably find more flaws.

So point me to something, please! I am sure we will see a problem similar to this one on our midterm, even though most of our exercises were about finding a single particular element from a sorted array, which is simple as heck to do in O(log n), but that's just how most professors are...

Comment: Two words: divide and conquer.

Comment: If you think I don't know this is divide and conquer, then you live in an illusion! If you actually want to be helpful and show some knowledge, then you'd need to elaborate a lot more on those 3 words.

Comment: You're overthinking it... O(log n + 10) is still considered as O(log n). And you can't do that is less than 10 iterations anyway.

Comment: ...as is `k * log(n)`, where k = 10.

Comment: Hint: What if you only needed to prove that the sorted array contained at least 2 distinct values?  Then consider 3 distinct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach is to examine the first element, and then use bisection to find the next element that is different to the first.  Bisection will take O(logn) steps.

Repeat this with the next element until you have found 10 distinct elements, or reached the end of the list.

This is complexity O(10.logn)=O(logn)

### Example

Suppose the input list was:

```
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

The way the process would continue is as follows:

```
1. Take first element (A[0]=1)
2. Examine A[8], this is 2 which is different
3. Examine A[4], this is 1 which is the same
4. Examine A[6], this is 1 which is the same
5. Examine A[7], this is 1 which is the same
6. Conclude that all elements from position 0 to 7 are the same element
```

At this point we have discovered 1 distinct element, we now continue the process starting with the 2.

Although we have not examined every element, because we know that the list is sorted we can be sure that all the ones we did not examine have value 1.

Comment: how can I apply the bisection method. It is still throwing out elements. Do i have to make a new, updated copy of the array at every iteration?

Comment: @RumenHristov example added.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will examine it.